# How to change Tfs web access style

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access

I want to change the style (like in css) of my tfs web access, I use scrum 2.0 template with tfs 2012 for my projects and want to change the style (like change the default white background color for example) of my project web page. does anybody know how to achieve this?

I noticed that there is a template in tfs folder that contains four .wsp files, does it have anything to do with them?

I already know that I can use browser add-ins like Stylish.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some CSS files you may be able to modify, but beware, this type of customization is totally unsupported, and may break on future TFS Upgrades (or may break TFS itself).

You can find them here:

> C:\Program files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Application Tier\Web Services\_static\tfs\11\App_Themes\Default\

Comment: So if this is not a recommended approach, what else can I do?

Comment: Use it as-is.  Web access doesn't support customization at this time.

Comment: You could also write a simple extension that just contained styles - see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ondrejstastny/archive/2012/11/27/tfs-2012-web-access-customizations-part-2-extension-template.aspx